# How do I set up a localhost in python?

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, localhost

The project is to be able to send email from within Python. I can successfully send to, for example, "smtp.gmail.com", but using a localhost or 127.0.0.1 returns an "errno 111, connection was refused." The statement is

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1', 8025)
```

Notes:
I am running Ubuntu, Python 3.2 or Python 2.7 depending on what the wonderful people here know best, and my programming knowledge could be charitably described as limited.

Comment: You need to install an SMTP server on your local machine.

Comment: Sending mail from your host is not trivial. You need to install and configure a mail gateway (e.g. sendmail, exim, courier). Also, they listen on port 25, not 8025, by default. You would have to configure it to send to a "smarter" host. Presumably you, your company, or your ISP already has a mail gateway and you can just use that. This is not a Python programming question, but an email admin question.

Comment: Do you actually want to send mail from your local machine or just debug that your mail messages are being formatted and sent to the SMTP server?

Answer (score 1):

First, [test your local SMTP connection using Telnet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx). (Alternate instructions [here](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/smtp.shtml)) This will tell if you can connect to your local SMTP server in the way you think you can.

You probably have one of several problems:

1. No SMTP server on your machine or;
2. You have SMTP but it requires a password and/or;
3. You have SMTP on your local machine but it is not configured properly or configured to support SMTP locally -> Internet or;
4. The machine's current IP or DNS setup or;
5. The way you are calling the local SMTP server from Python.

Python SMTPlib supports authorized connections using LMTP for issue 2.

Try using port 25 for issue 5.

For the other issues, you will need to find or [setup](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch21_%3a_Configuring_Linux_Mail_Servers) a cooperative SMTP server.

BTW: properly configuring and securing an SMTP server is not trivial...

Comment: How do I test a local SMTP connection in Ubuntu? Sorry for not including that in the original post, I have edited it.

Comment: Use `$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8025` If it says `Connection refused` or some other error -- that is your problem. If you get inside a valid SMTP server, follow the step-by-step instruction I linked to. If you can successfully send email by connecting with the SMTP host using telnet -- you should be good to go.

Comment: Connection refused. Thank you for your time.

Note: I am not trying to make a secure server that can receive emails. I was hoping that sending emails would be relatively trivial.

Comment: @Celer: Try with port 25 like so: `$ telnet 127.0.0.1 25`

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do, is using the local machine as the smtp-server.  The simplest way to achieve this in Ubuntu, would be to install one of the exim4 or postfix-packages in apt / synaptic ...

Make sure that when prompted, that you don't allow machines you don't trust to use your host as a mail-relay.  The defaults should be sufficient to avoid this - yet still allow mail to be sent from your machine.

Also note that the default port-number for smtp is port 25, and not 8025 as in your code example.